# Combining data from 2 databases in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am fairly new to asp.net mvc and I currently have an application that shows a number of errors. I have 2 pages that contain Application Errors and Log Errors. The data comes from 2 different databases but I am wanting to display the data from both databases on one page.

The tables have headings with different names that mean the same thing e.g. ApplicationName in the Application Database is the same thing as LogName in the Log Database.

Below is a small example of what I currently have and an example of what I am wanting.

**Current**

```
Application Errors

ID   ApplicationName    ApplicationMessage     ApplicationDate

1    Something          Hello World            01/01/2015
2    Something Else     Another Message        03/01/2015


Log Errors

ID   LogName            LogMessage             LogDate

1    Some Log           A log message          02/01/2015
2    Another Log        Another Log Message    04/01/2015
```

**What I Want**

```
Internal Errors

ID   Name               Message                Date

1    Something          Hello World            01/01/2015
2    Some Log           A log message          02/01/2015
3    Something Else     Another Message        03/01/2015
4    Another Log        Another Log Message    04/01/2015
```

At the minute, I have 2 separate models for each database but I think I need to merge both models into one model that combines them both but I am unsure on how to do this. How would I be able to merge both data sources together to display the data within the same page?

**Current Models**

**Application**

```
    [Table("ELMAH_Error")]
    public class ElmahError
    {
        [Key]
        public System.Guid ErrorId { get; set; }

        public System.String Application { get; set; }
        public System.String Host { get; set; }
        public System.String Type { get; set; }
        public System.String Source { get; set; }
        public System.String Message { get; set; }
        public System.String User { get; set; }
        public System.Int32 StatusCode { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime TimeUtc { get; set; }
        public System.Int32 Sequence { get; set; }
        public System.String AllXml { get; set; }
    }
```

**Log**

```
    [Table("LogEntry")]
    public class LogEntry
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
        public Int16 Priority { get; set; }
        public string SourceClass { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string ProcessID { get; set; }
    }
```

From the models, there are a number of fields that I would like to merge as well as fields that are not similar that I would also like to include. The model below shows exactly what I want but I just don't know how to implement it.

**Internal Errors**

```
    public class InternalErrors
    {

        public string Id { get; set; } //L:ID && E:ErrorId
        public int Priority { get; set; } //L:Priority
        public string Application { get; set; } //L:SourceClass && E:Application
        public string Message { get; set; } //L:Message && E:Message
        public string Type { get; set; } //L:Category && E:Type
        public string User { get; set; } //L:UserID && E:User
        public string ProcessID { get; set; } //L:ProcessID
        public DateTime Date { get; set; } //L:LogDate && E:TimeUtc
        public int StatusCode { get; set; } //E:StatusCode
        public string AllXml { get; set; } //E:AllXml
        public int Sequence { get; set; } //E:Sequence
        public int ErrorCount { get; set; } //E:ErrorCount
    }
```

I hope this is enough information for you to provide an answer, if you need anything else, let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you talking about this https://dotnetfiddle.net/mrWGDn ?

Comment: What are you using to connect to the database? EF, raw ado.net, what is it? You'll probably want to add that as a tag too.

Answer (score 2):

if what you want is this

```
Internal Errors

ID   Name               Message                Date

1    Something          Hello World            01/01/2015
2    Some Log           A log message          02/01/2015
3    Something Else     Another Message        03/01/2015
4    Another Log        Another Log Message    04/01/2015
```

then create a class with name InternalErrors as follows.

```
public class InternalErrors
{
       public int ID;
       public string Name;
       public string Message;
       public DateTime Date;
}
```

Now you can write a Linq Query as follows to get data from Application Errors and Log Errors and Perform union on it.

```
var AppErrors=from AE in _db.ApplicationErrors select AE;
var LogErrors=from LE in _dc.LogErrors select LE;
var internerrors=AppErrors.Union(LogErrors);
var InternalErrors=(from ie in internerrors select new InternalErrors()
                      {
                          ID=ie.ID,
                          Message=ie.ApplicationMessage,
                          Name=ie.ApplicationName,
                          Date=ie.ApplicationDate
                      }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The viewmodel approach from MRebati is the best solution.

I often find it usefull to have a base class and different implementations:

```
public abstract class ErrorViewModel
{

    public abstract int Id { get; }

    public abstract string Name { get; }
}

public class ElmahErrorViewModel
{
    public ElmahErrorViewModel(ElmahError instance)
    {
        this.Instance = instance;
    }

    public ElmahError Instance { get; private set; }

    public int Id { get { return Instance.ErrorId; } }

    public string Name { get { return instance.Appication; } }
}
```

that way you can create a `List<ErrorViewModel>` and add entries with

```
var items = from e in context.ElmahErrors
            select new ElmahErrorViewModel(e);

list.AddRange(items);

var items2 = from l in context.LogEntrys
             select new LogEntryViewModel(l);

list.AddRange(items2);
```

This is very usefull since you hide the details but you still can seprate the list and access the underlying object with

```
var elmahErrors = items.OfType<ElmahErrorViewModel>().Select(x => x.Instance);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to provide data from the models to the View.
One is the ViewModel. It must contain the data you want to send to view. Look at this:

```
using System;

public class ErrorViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

And in the Controller you need to Create a list of this ViewModel and populate it with your data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `linq`

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var elmahErrorList = new List<ElmahError>{
            new ElmahError{ ErrorId = Guid.NewGuid(), Application = "Something",Message = "Hello World" , TimeUtc = DateTime.Now },
                new ElmahError{ ErrorId = Guid.NewGuid(), Application = "Something Else",Message = "Another Message" , TimeUtc = DateTime.Now }
        };

        var logEntryList = new List<LogEntry>{
            new LogEntry{ ID = 1, SourceClass = "Something",Message = "Hello World" , LogDate = DateTime.Now },
                new LogEntry{ ID = 1, SourceClass = "Something Else",Message = "Another Message" , LogDate = DateTime.Now }
        };

        var internalErrorsList = new List<InternalErrors>();

        var elmahErrorListinternalErrorses = elmahErrorList.Select(e => new InternalErrors
                                                                   {
                                                                       Id = e.ErrorId.ToString(),
                                                                       Application = e.Application,
                                                                       Message = e.Message,
                                                                       Type = e.Type,
                                                                       User = e.User,
                                                                       Date = e.TimeUtc,
                                                                       StatusCode = e.StatusCode,
                                                                       AllXml = e.AllXml,
                                                                       Sequence = e.Sequence
                                                                   });

        internalErrorsList.AddRange(elmahErrorListinternalErrorses);

        var elmahErrorListlogEntryLists = logEntryList.Select(l => new InternalErrors
                                                              {
                                                                  Id = l.ID.ToString(),
                                                                  Priority = l.Priority,
                                                                  Application = l.SourceClass,
                                                                  Message = l.Message,
                                                                  Type = l.Category,
                                                                  User = l.UserID,
                                                                  Date = l.LogDate
                                                              });
        internalErrorsList.AddRange(elmahErrorListlogEntryLists);

        internalErrorsList.ForEach(f =>
                                   {
                                       Console.Write(f.Id); Console.Write("\t");
                                       Console.Write(f.Application);Console.Write("\t");
                                       Console.Write(f.Message);Console.Write("\t");
                                       Console.Write(f.Date);Console.Write("\t");
                                       Console.WriteLine();
                                   });

    }
    public class InternalErrors
    {
        public string Id { get; set; } //L:ID && E:ErrorId
        public int Priority { get; set; } //L:Priority
        public string Application { get; set; } //L:SourceClass && E:Application
        public string Message { get; set; } //L:Message && E:Message
        public string Type { get; set; } //L:Category && E:Type
        public string User { get; set; } //L:UserID && E:User
        public string ProcessID { get; set; } //L:ProcessID
        public DateTime Date { get; set; } //L:LogDate && E:TimeUtc
        public int StatusCode { get; set; } //E:StatusCode
        public string AllXml { get; set; } //E:AllXml
        public int Sequence { get; set; } //E:Sequence
        public int ErrorCount { get; set; } //E:ErrorCount
    }
    public class ElmahError
    {
        public System.Guid ErrorId { get; set; }
        public System.String Application { get; set; }
        public System.String Host { get; set; }
        public System.String Type { get; set; }
        public System.String Source { get; set; }
        public System.String Message { get; set; }
        public System.String User { get; set; }
        public System.Int32 StatusCode { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime TimeUtc { get; set; }
        public System.Int32 Sequence { get; set; }
        public System.String AllXml { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogEntry
    {
        public Int64 ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
        public Int16 Priority { get; set; }
        public string SourceClass { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string ProcessID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/mrWGDn